# How to view design inspector in flutter without Android studio or Intelij?

Tags: flutter

In Intelij can view the inspector tab with each object with a background color, but how to make this without IntelliJ ide?, I run my project from bash and use Atom as code editor.

I can set a red border for all widgets in the `ThemeData` or like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're refer to Flutter Inspector Tab, You can used it any IDE. This [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/cli) describe the steps to set up debug the application.

In short, these are the steps to follow,

1. Run the Flutter Application, you should see output that looks something like: `The Flutter DevTools debugger is available at http://127.0.0.1:9100?uri=http://127.0.0.1`
2. Open the above link in any browser
3. Flutter Inspector tab will be open by default.

If you want to learn more about Flutter DevTools check out the [Official Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/overview)